# why avoid setting refs during rendering?

Tags: reactjs

I read https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html recently, and I saw this: "Unless you’re doing lazy initialization, avoid setting refs during rendering — this can lead to surprising behavior. Instead"

I want to know why should we avoid setting refs during rendering, and what bug will happen in this scenes

In fact, I always set ref during rendering, and have no problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be conflating the attaching of a ref to an element/component with the setting of the ref's current value. You attach ref's to DOM elements or other React components in the "render" method, but can set the current value of a ref just about anytime you can.

I think the "surprising behavior" the docs refer to are value mutations. React refs don't live within the confines of a component lifecycle, i.e. the "bookends" where values are generally considered "constant", stable, and reliable. Their value can be updated at any time *during* a render cycle.

I do find it a bit odd that React would call out something leading to "surprising behavior" and then not go into any detail about it, but hopefully you can see the edge case here where logic may have been implemented with stable values in mind using a ref and the ref value is mutated in the middle of the render cycle. This is likely the reasoning for suggesting that they typically be modified in event handlers and effects where the scope of the function keeps the mutation contained.